# Best practice for "unused template parameter" in C++

Tags: c++, templates, void

Given a template class such as

```
template <class Key, class Value> 
class CustomMap {
    // standard map implementation here, with (say) 'put', 'contains' and 'get'
};
```

and assuming that I do not care for the `Value` parameter (as I wish to use the map as a set), and that I cannot use standard C++ containers, what is the recommended way to indicate this?

One option would be use a typedefs:

```
typedef UNUSED int;
const UNUSED UNUSED_VALUE = 0;
CustomMap<std::string, UNUSED> map;
map.put("test", UNUSED_VALUE);
cout << map.contains("test");
```

What would you recommend in this case? Evidently, `CustomMap<std::string, void>` does not compile, since references to `void` are invalid. I cannot change the implementation of `CustomMap`, nor can I add a `CustomSet` to complement it.

NOTE: these requirements come from an educational setting; therefore, the most readable and understandable answer is being sought. This answer may well be "add a comment explaining why you use an int"...

Comment: You may want to use a `char` instead of an `int` as it utilizes less memory but I am not sure if that will ultimately affect your custom set/map...Why not use std::set?.

Comment: My advice would be "don't do it".  a set is not a map.

Comment: You should use a `struct dummy_struct{};` (**not** an `int`). And you should wrap the whole thing in your own class, so that the messiness of adapting a `map` to a `set` is only in one place.

Comment: this is for "blackboard code" -- but I really, really like the dummy_struct idea (also advocated by @Mike_Seymour)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Sure, but sometimes libraries supply maps but not sets (for example, [Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has [concurrent_hash_map](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506077) but no concurrent_hash_set.)

Comment: What's wrong with building the data structure based on a comparator, and then using that data structure to provide two interfaces: set and map, in the same way that most implementations of the STL have an underlying balanced tree structure and different interfaces?  The current approach will require you to waste some space when using this as just a set (you will still need the value, at least 1 byte, plus padding) to be added to each node... Now that I think of it, it might be a bit too much for what is expected from you, but you will really learn from the experience.

Comment: This is for "blackboard code" for essentially C++ novices (actually using laptop+projector). I cannot fit anything really verbose inside, even if it is more efficient or correct. I was looking for a less-dirty quick-and-dirty answer. Currently, "use a dummy struct" is winning.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - I will advocate for a change in teaching materials next year, decoupling inner implementations from public API. That would yield a Map, a Set, and both would use a SortedTree. Same for hashes. You are right regarding added educational value.

Comment: I am not sure it will take a lot of time to work out the refactor, and you can probably rewrite the existing `CustomMap` into a `SortedTree` and then build `Map` and `Set` in one or two hours tops. Students might be a bit puzzled, but will probably get the *coolness* of generalizing an existing solution into something more powerful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use an empty class rather than a mildly confusing alias for `int`:

```
struct nothing {};
CustomMap<std::string, nothing> map;
map.put("test", nothing());
```

I also wouldn't use SHOUTY_CAPS; as well as being harder to read, they're conventionally reserved for macros, to reduce the danger of the preprocessor stomping over language-level names.

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for. Short, self-explaining, and no messiness finding a matching value

Comment: You could also add a wrapper method like `CustomMap<Key, Value>::insert(const Key& key) { Impl::put(Key, Value()); }` (where `Impl` is the implementation class) so you can then say simply `map.insert("test");` and it looks more like a set.

Comment: @tucuxi Default template parameters could help on situations like this, for example: `template<typename Key , typename Value = dummy_tag>` or even `template<typename key , typename value = key>` (The later is very similar to `std::set`, where keys and values are the same). Both options play well with partial specialization. Other solution (via C++11 template aliases) could be `template<typename Key> using CustomSet = CustomMap<Key,dummy_tag>;` Thanks to the alias the usage is much more clear.

Comment: @tucuxi finally to make the interface of your ADT more clear, I suggest you to make the value argumment of `put`-like functions optional (Supposing `Value` is default constructible): `put( const Key& key , const Value& value = Value{} );` If not, one could use SFINAE and `std::is_default_constructible` trait.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if they HAD to be the same name, I'd probably use a specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename... J>
class OptionalSet;

template <typename T>
class OptionalSet
{
  //implementation of non-keyed thing
};

template <typename T, typename J>
class OpionalSet
{
  //implimentation of keyed thing
};
```

But the big thing is a set and a map are not the same, and making them the same class is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks, but this is too verbose for the intended setting: classroom, working with existing Map implementation and improvising a Set for a particular problem.

Comment: Yes, variadic macros are a cool new feature. No, I don't think this is a good use of it. There are only two implementations, and you need to specialize. Just provide the two implementations `OptionalSet<K>`, `OptionalSet<K,V>` and call them `Set` and `Map`